# .(Theory Problem) If A is a 3 × 4 matrix with 3 pivots then what can be said about the system of equations Ax = b?

Tags: linear-algebra

My guess is that A has a pivot position in every row about a coefficient matrix. So Ax=b must be a solution if b is a linear combination of all the columns of A but I'm not sure what else is there to add about this question.

Comment: Are you familiar with the terms injective and surjective functions?  (*also called one-to-one and onto functions respectively*)  Are you familiar with any theorems linking whether a matrix has linearly independent rows with its injectivity or surjectivity?  How about linearly independent columns to its injectivity or surjectivity?

Comment: As an alternate hint, consider the rank-nullity theorem.  What does the number of pivots have to do with the dimension of the nullspace or kernel?  What does that imply about the number of solutions to $Ax=b$ if we know at least one solution exists?  Do we know that at least one solution exists?

Comment: What you state is true of _any_ system $Ax=b$. You’re not using any of the given conditions.